# Adjust WebView when keyboard is opened in Android

Tags: android, webview, popup, android-softkeyboard

I created an app in which I used WebView for navigation on site pages.

```
   browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.customWebBrowser);

   browser.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
   browser.setWebChromeClient(new CustomWebChromeClient());
   browser.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchBrowser());
```

The problem is when I tap link "login" and a pop-up window is opened for input of login/password. When keyboard has risen it coves login/password pop-up and I can`t see what symbols I entered, content of visible WebView is not adjusted.

I tried to fix this issue by using **windowSoftInputMode** parameter in AndroidManifest.xml but it hasnt any effect. I think that's because of using pop-up window on server side.

How to fix this issue so screen will be adjusted when keyboard has risen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for my issue. It`s based on yghm's workaround.

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5497

```
public class AndroidBug5497Workaround {

    // For more information, see https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5497
    // To use this class, simply invoke assistActivity() on an Activity that already has its content view set.

    public static void assistActivity (Activity activity) {
        new AndroidBug5497Workaround(activity);
    }

    private View mChildOfContent;
    private int usableHeightPrevious;
    private FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameLayoutParams;

    private AndroidBug5497Workaround(Activity activity) {
        FrameLayout content = (FrameLayout) activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        mChildOfContent = content.getChildAt(0);
        mChildOfContent.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                possiblyResizeChildOfContent();
            }
        });
        frameLayoutParams = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) mChildOfContent.getLayoutParams();
    }

    private void possiblyResizeChildOfContent() {
        int usableHeightNow = computeUsableHeight();
        if (usableHeightNow != usableHeightPrevious) {
            int usableHeightSansKeyboard = mChildOfContent.getRootView().getHeight();
            int heightDifference = usableHeightSansKeyboard - usableHeightNow;
            if (heightDifference > (usableHeightSansKeyboard/4)) {
                // keyboard probably just became visible
                frameLayoutParams.height = usableHeightSansKeyboard - heightDifference;
            } else {
                // keyboard probably just became hidden
                frameLayoutParams.height = usableHeightSansKeyboard;
            }
            mChildOfContent.requestLayout();
            usableHeightPrevious = usableHeightNow;
        }
    }

    private int computeUsableHeight() {
        Rect r = new Rect();
        mChildOfContent.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
        return (r.bottom - r.top);
    }

}
```

Using this class in OnCreate-method of Activity:

```
AndroidBug5497Workaround.assistActivity(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Catch events from IME and manually adjust the WebView height